# Stop Flash Builder parsing XML file

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm editing an XML file in Flash Builder 4.6, the XML contains config data and is embedded into my application.

Flash Builder shows a long list of errors, the errors are linked to the project not the file.

The errors are just things like "*1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon*" and "*1093: Syntax error*" which just shows that the file is not valid Actionscript.

They all look like this, with the error on line 1:

[image: Error Msg]

Is there a way that I can stop the parsing of the file, it's just an asset and not supposed to be parsed.

Comment: Don't put it in a source folder? Nevertheless, it shouldn't be doing this. You _could_ also switch to a proper IDE ;)

Comment: @RIAstar: I always put my assets folder in the src path, so I embed with `@Embed('assets/something/else.xml')`. Maybe I will have to change to `'..assets/something/else.xml'`

Comment: @RIAstar Maybe I will try IntelliJ IDEA, sick of FB now. I tried upgrading to 4.7 (64 bit) this week and it's broken and slow. What IDE do you recommend?

Comment: The one you had in mind is my weapon of choice. Though you should know that it comes with a learning curve if you're used to Eclipse. I needed about two weeks to get up to the speed I had with FB, but after that I kept getting more productive. Here's a [FAQ for Eclipse users](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html). The one thing I really liked in the migration process was the ability to reset the keyboard shortcuts to the ones used in Eclipse (if applicable of course, 'cause there's so much more).

Comment: This has nothing to do with FlashBuilder. 1. Does your XML is in a consistent form (try open it with IE or Firefox, is all ok). 2. Do you have XML validation enabled inside FlashBuilder ?

Comment: Since you're embedding the file already, how about putting your XML in an Actionscript class? You can declare a variable of type XML and paste in the XML from your assets file. This may get around the parsing issues, and is basically no different than embedding it (except that it will probably consume less memory than the embedded file).

Answer (score 0):

There are several compiler params you can pass when you are compiling your appliation, following link you can visit - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_4.html.

On the given link it is defined that you can provide your config file link as follows -

```
<mxmlc ... >
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
    <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
</mxmlc>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really help. My xml file is embedded using the `@Embed` syntax, it's an asset file that resides in the `src` directory.

Comment: Can;t you load your XML file at runtime with help of HTTPService call?

Comment: Yes, but that's not really the issue. The problem is that the file in my assets directory is being passed & evaluated by Flash Builder.

Comment: Please remove @Embed tag from the XML and remove any clue of culprit XML than add an EventListener at initialize or CreationComplete event and load the XML with service call. Hope this will resolve you problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but I want to embed the file into the swf, I don't want the file to be remote. It doesn't matter, I will switch IDEs

Comment: @Gerve My comment was intended as a pun you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

declaration
in your xml file and the compiler errors should be gone

Comment: I think the problem is because I have international characters and the charset is UTF-16. I have already fixed by embedding the file as a `String` instead of a `Class`